# Converting logical partition to primary partition

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning

I am booting windows on ubuntu 14.04 but during the time of installing it is just showing logical partition who can I convert logical partition into primary partition to install windows alongside with ubuntu.

```
$ sudo parted -l
```

Shows following output as screenshot:

[image]

Comment: You can only have 4 primary partitions, so how many do you have? Post this: sudo parted -l Generally better to have Windows as the first partition but not required. But if Linux is a logical partition, not only will Windows overwrite MBR, but will rewrite partition table without Linux partition. Make sure you have working live Ubuntu installer to make repairs. And best to have Windows partition before the extended. http://www.rodsbooks.com/fixparts/

Comment: I too am looking for a convenient way to do this from Linux. Sadly, GParted does not have this yet.  Many Partition tools for Windows make this a breeze.  In the past I've had to hand-edit C/H/S partition table boundaries and the Type field, all in binary--just to "trick" the OS while keeping all actual data in place--but I prefer to not have to still do it this way.